# BULK INSERT Task Issues

Tags: sql-server, ssis, package, ssms, bulkinsert

First, I am new to SSIS so I am still getting the hang of things.

I am using Visual Studio 19 and SSMS 19

Regardless, I have set-up an OLE DB Package from .TSV file to table in SSMS. The issue is that it took 1 hour and 11 minutes to execute for 500,000 rows.

The data is extremely variable so I have set-up a staging table in SSMS that is essentially all varchar(max) columns. Once all the data is inserted, then I was going to look at some aggregations like max(len(<column_name>)) in order to better optimize the table and the SSIS package.

Anyways, there are 10 of these files so I need to create a ForEach File loop. This would take at minimum (1.17 hours)*10=11.70 hours of total runtime.

I thought this was a bit long and created a BULK INSERT Task, but I am having some issues.
It seems very straightforward to set-up.

I added the Bulk Insert Task to the Control Flow tab and went into the Bulk Insert Task Editor Dialogue Box.

From here, I configured the Source and Destination connections. Both of which went very smoothly. I only have one local instance of SQL Server on my machine so I used localhost.<database_name> and the table name for the Destination Connection.

I run the package and it executes just fine without any errors or warnings. It takes less than a minute for a roughly 600 MB .TSV file to load into a SSMS table with about 300 columns of varchar(max).

I thought this was too quick and it was. ***Nothing loaded, but the package executed!!!***

I have tried searching for this issue with no success. I checked my connections too.

Do I need Data Flow Tasks for Bulk Insert Tasks? Do I need any connection managers? I had to configure Data Flow Tasks and connection managers for the OLE DB package, but the articles I have referenced do not do this for Bulk Insert Tasks.

What am I doing wrong?

Any advice from someone more well-versed in SSIS would be much appreciated.

Comment: *"The data is extremely variable so I have set-up a staging table in SSMS that is essentially all varchar(max) columns"* This seems like the first problem you should be addressing. You're saying that all of your columns could be up to 2GB in size/2 **billion** characters in length. I doubt that is even close to true. Yes, they might be varying width, but I doubt that every column needs to be a `MAX` size, not need to be a `varchar`. I would start by redefining your data as best you can, not just dumping everything in a `varchar(MAX)`. I would only expect one `MAX` column, *maybe* 2, per table.

Comment: Bulk Insert tasks are very fussy and do not perform better than a regular data flow.  In my own benchmarking, they are actually worse.  I suggest going back to the dataflow approach and tune that.  There are so many things I could recommend but the first is to reduce the column size like @Larnu noted.  Take a file source and attach that to a derived column, remove any destination and see how long that read takes

Comment: Thank you Larnu! I will do that. Do you know of any good mechanisms to potentially extract column definitions? I changed the parameters of "Suggested Data Types" to first 100,000 rows and padding percentage of 25%, 20%, 15%, and then 10%....all failed.

Comment: Thank you as well Mark! I will optimize the destination table. Also, I will complete the OLE DB package as well and see which one performs better. I was under the assumption from the light research that I had performed that Bulk Insert tasks may perform better. If that is not necessarily the case, then I will try both. Also, Mark, how would I perform the last sentence in your comment? Sorry, like I said, I am relatively new.

Comment: I have adjusted the table, but have been pulled away for another task (for the time being). If it is alright, I will have to return to this tomorrow. I will update the post as necessary. I apologize for any inconvenience.

Comment: I am picking this back up now. I adjusted the columns definitions of the table in SSMS. I am now configuring the Connection Manager to the .TSV file to mirror that table definition.

Comment: Hi MarkWojciechowicz and Larnu. I have decided to stick with the OLE DB Connection and ditch the Bulk Insert Task per Mark's recommendation (also, it was not working how I wanted it to). Regardless, after optimizations, the run-time went from an hour and 11 minutes to 41 minutes. Considering the variable data I dare not make the column defs any smaller at the moment. The Foreach File Loop is running and seems to be doing so successfully. Hopefully, nothing exceeds the minimized column definitions, but I gave significant padding (much less than varchar(max)). We will see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding my comment about using a derived column in place of a real destination, it would look like 1 in the image below.  You can do this in a couple of steps:

1. Run the read task only and see how long this takes.  Limit the total read to a sample size so your test does not take an hour.
2. Run the read task with a derived column as a destination.  This will test the total read time, plus the amount of time to load the data into memory.

If 1) takes a long time, it could indicate a bottleneck with slow read times on the disk where the file is or a network bottleneck if the file is on another server on a shared drive.  If 2) adds a lot more time, it could indicate a memory bottleneck on the server that SSIS is running.  Please note that you testing this on a server is the best way to test performance, because it removes a lot of issues that probably won't exist there such as network bottlenecks and memory constraints.

Lastly, please turn on the feature noted as 2) below, AutoAdjustBufferSize.  This will change the settings for DefaultBufferSize (max memory in the buffer) and DefaultBufferMaxRows (total rows allowed in each buffer, these are the numbers that you see next to the arrows in the dataflow when you run the package interactively).  Because your column sizes are so large, this will give a hint to the server to maximize the buffer size which gives you a bigger and faster pipeline to push the data through.

One final note, if you add the real destination and that has a significant impact on time, you can look into issues with the target table.  Make sure there are no indexes including a cluster index, make sure tablock is on, make sure there are no constraints or triggers.

[image]